# Rebuilding Perl the get it ready for padre

Tags: perl

When I tried to install padre I got a message that I need a Perl with ithreads enabled.
So when I rebuild my Perl, are these configure-options OK?

```
sh Configure -de -Duseithreads
```

And if I rebuild Perl from the same source-files which I used for the actual Perl can I keep my already installed modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use perlbrew for compiling Perl. Are you installing the same version of Perl in exactly the same place? Probably. But I would prefer to reinstall them...

See my howto on the subject padre - perlbrew - cpanminus: http://nxadm.wordpress.com/2010/12/10/build-padre-svn-easily-with-perlbrew-and-cpanm/